# Разбор работы perfect forwarding в примере

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, типы-данных, language-lawyer

Объясните подробно, пожалуйста, как это работает и почему выводит `&&`.

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

void foo(const std::string&) {
    std::cout << "&\n";
}

void foo(std::string&& s) {
    std::cout << "&&\n";
}

template<typename T>
void bar(T&& s) {
    foo(std::forward<T>(s));
}

int main() {
    bar("42");
}
```

Какие типы и почему у `"42"`, `T`, `s` в параметре, `s` внутри функции `bar`, `std::forward<T>(s)` и почему вызов функции `foo` с аргументом последнего типа вызывает именно перегрузку для rvalue?

Comment: потому что "42" и есть  rvalue,string

Comment: @ARHovsepyan хотелось бы более подробного объяснения

Comment: Ну вы же не можете написать присваивание string("42") = "153"?  Если вам подробно об универсальных ссылках, то  об этом уже много написано по интернету, не считая учебники.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сразу скажу, в приведенном примере что perfect forwarding и наличие универсальной ссылки никакой роли в выборе перегрузки не играет. Перегрузка `foo(std::string&& s)` вызывается, так как при вызове `foo(std::forward<T>(s));` в любом случае будет создаваться временный объект `::std::string` с вызовом конструктора, принимающего `char const *`.

Более корректный пример выглядит так:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

void foo(const std::string&) {
    std::cout << "&\n";
}

void foo(std::string&& s) {
    std::cout << "&&\n";
}

template<typename T>
void bar(T&& s) {
    foo(std::forward<T>(s));
}

int main() {
    ::std::string lval{};
    // lvalue reference
    bar(lval); // foo(const std::string &)
    // rvalue reference
    bar(::std::move(lval)); // foo(std::string &&)
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6dD3u5

При передаче на вход lvalue универсальная ссылка будет lvalue reference, после форвардинга вызовется перегрузка, принимающая lvalue reference. При передаче на вход rvalue универсальная ссылка будет rvalue reference, после форвардинга вызовется перегрузка, принимающая rvalue reference.

Comment: Почему это более корректный пример, когда это другой пример?) Меня интересует именно `"42"`, то как это происходит при аргументе типа `std::string` я и так понимаю. В предыдущем ответе уже объяснил же это.

Comment: @poll я же написал - в вашем примере  perfect forwarding и наличие универсальной ссылки никакой роли в выборе перегрузки не играет.

Comment: Я не утверждаю, что он играет роль. Мне интересно подробно разобраться, какие типы у всех "передаваемых сущностей", чтобы точно понимать, что происходит, а не на уровне "ок, "42" временный объект => вызовется перегрузка с rvalue".

Comment: @poll я это тоже уже написал - единственный конструктор, который может быть вызван для параметра `"42"` (`char const [3]`) или `char const *` или любых вариантов их lvalue / revalue reference вариантов - это конструктор std::string, принимающий `char const *`.

Comment: Согласен. Но мне непонятно, как из этого следует ответ на вопрос "какие типы у всех "передаваемых сущностей"".

Comment: @poll Каких именно сущностей? Тут только есть "42" (char const [3]), `T` в шаблоне - ссылка на `char const [3]` ну и временный объект `::std::string`.

Comment: Я указал минимальный список в вопросе. Повторяю: "Какие типы и почему у "42", T, s в параметре, s внутри функции bar, std::forward<T>(s) и почему вызов функции foo с аргументом последнего типа вызывает именно перегрузку для rvalue?"

Comment: С типом `"42"` согласен. Почему у `T` тип `char const (&) [3]`? А какие дальше типы?

Comment: что то мне кажется, что poll, ueber и ещё пара - это один человек. Очень похожий стиль трольства.  Однотипные вопросы, однотипные "объясните".

Comment: @KoVadim зачем вы засоряете комментарии? Если вы считаете вопрос троллингом, то ставьте минус и тревогу на закрытие. То что для вас очевидно, может быть не очевидно для других.

Comment: @poll у `T` тип `char const (&) [3]` потому что строковые литералы биндятся к lvalue ссылкам. T, s в параметре, s внутри функции bar, std::forward<T>(s) имеют одинаковый тип

Comment: @user7860670 хм, если они имеют одинаковый тип, то зачем нужен форвард вообще? Одинаковый это какой? `char const (&&) [3]`?

Comment: @user7860670 останавливайтесь. Вы не сможете его переубедить.

Comment: @poll  "T, s в параметре, s внутри функции bar, std::forward<T>(s) имеют одинаковый тип" - "у T тип char const (&) [3]", а в вашем примере форвард действительно не нужен...

Comment: @user7860670 ок, остался последний вопрос. Почему вызов `foo` с аргументом типа `char const (&) [3]` вызывает именно вариант с rvalue ссылкой, это же lvalue ссылка? Потому что временный объект `std::string` конструируется ДО overload resolution, так?

Comment: @poll временный `std::string` из `char const (&) [3]` необходимо создавать как при вызове `foo(const std::string&)`, так и при вызове  `foo(std::string&&)` но второй вариант с точки зрения overload resolution будет предпочтительнее

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо, вопрос исчерпан. Пойду почитаю про overload resolution в стандарте, чтобы понять почему это так.

Answer (score 4):

По-хорошему, у вас должно передаваться в `bar` не `"42"`, а `"42"s`, потому что иначе выполняется еще и сбивающее с толку преобразование литерала в строку. Тип литерала "42" у вас - `const char[3]`, так что...

Но вот если сделать так -

```
template<typename T>
void bar(T&& s) {
    foo(s);
    foo(std::forward<T>(s));
}

int main() {
    bar("42"s);
}
```

то тут и будет видно, в чем польза от `forward`. Дело в том, что `T&&` - это не ссылка на rvalue, а универсальная ссылка, которая может быть и ссылкой на rvalue, и на lvalue. Но ваш параметр `s`, будучи именуемой переменной, от которой можно брать адрес, внутри функции-шаблона булет рассматриваться как lvalue. Чему доказательство первый вызов

```
    foo(s);
```

каковой выводит `&`. Но вот второй вызов выведет `&&`, потому что `forward` превратит `s` из lvalue в то, чем он был при входе в `foo` - в ссылку на `rvalue`.

А вот если передавать в `bar` lvalue -

```
string s;
bar(s);
```

то оба `foo` выведут `&`, так как в данном случае `forward` оставит параметр тем, чем он был и есть - lvalue.

При передаче *именно* `"42"`, `T` выводится как `char const [3]`, так что является rvalue, и вызывается перегрузка для rvalue что при использовании `forward`, что без него.

P.S. Для особых ценителей точности формулировок - вполне допускаю, что где-то использовал термины не совсем верно :( - поправляйте.

Comment: Так меня интересует именно `"42"`, а не `"42"s`.

Comment: "42" - `const char[3]`, T - `char const (&)[3]`

Comment: А тут вы передаете строку, которая, будучи литералом, передается как `const char[3]`, именно так выводится ее тип, и является `rvalue` в обоих случаях, так что вызывается `foo(&&)`.

Comment: @KoVadim а дальше?

Comment: @Harry ок, пусть литерал такого типа. А какие типы дальше?

Comment: А дальше вызывается `foo(string&&)`, потому что мы имеем дело с rvalue, которое преобразуется в `string&&` - раз таковой вариант есть. Если бы его не было, выполнялось бы преобразование в `const string&`.

Comment: А дальше все очевидно

Comment: Меня интересуют конкретные типы и почему они такие. Мне не очевидно почему вызывается указанная перегрузка.

Comment: Что именно неясно - `char const [3]`, или преобразование в `string`?

Comment: @Harry то что `"42"` литерал такого типа ясно. Какие типы дальше неясно (минимальный список я привёл в вопросе).

Comment: *"42"* - `char const [3]`, *T* - `char const [3]`, *`s` в параметре, s внутри функции bar* - ссылка на `char const [3]`, *std::forward<T>(s)* - `char const (&&)[3]`. Вроде бы так.

Comment: @Harry почему именно такие? А если такие, то почему вызов `foo(char const (&&)[3])` приводит к вызову указанной перегрузки?

Comment: @Harry - T - это `char const (&)[3]`

Comment: _Дело в том, что `T&&` - это не ссылка на rvalue, а универсальная ссылка_ [A _forwarding reference_ **is an rvalue reference** to ...](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.call#def:forwarding_reference)

Comment: @Harry, ваше объяснение понятное и практичное, но вот наткнулся на правила свёрток (A& & becomes A&;
A& && becomes A&;
A&& & becomes A&;
A&& && becomes A&&) и они вводят в ступор. Такое ощущение, что только две последние из них выполняются. Стоит ли ими пользоваться на практике?

Comment: @Elvin Лучше бы тут спросить какого гуру в стандартах или тщательно поизучать литературу... Я, как в "Петре I" Толстого — "сие не филозофы, но более люди наук практических" :) Когда сталкиваюсь с тем, что что-то работает не так, как я ожидал после прочтения книг, тогда уже вкапываюсь глубоко. Так что на ваш вопрос ответить мне сложно...

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR версия:

```
|            Вопрос            |                      Ответ                       |
| ---------------------------- | ------------------------------------------------ |
|         литерал "42"         |                  const char [3]                  |
|       дедуцированный T       |                const char (&) [3]                |
|          параметр s          |                const char (&) [3]                |
|         выражение s          |                  const char [3]                  |
| выражение std::forward<T>(s) |                  const char [3]                  |
|  вызов foo(std::string&& s)  | единственно лучший вариант в overload resolution |
```

---

---

Выражение `"42"` — [строковый литерал](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/lex.literal#nt:string-literal). Строковый литерал, который не начинается с префиксов `u8`, `u`, `U` и `L`, называется *обыкновенным строковым литералом* ([ordinary string literal](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/lex.string#def:ordinary_string_literal)). Для таких строковых литералов тип определяется следующим образом.

[[lex.string]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/lex.string#5):

> ... **An ordinary string literal has type “array of n const char”
> where n is the size of the string** as defined below, has static
> storage duration, and is initialized with the given characters.

Осталось узнать `n`. Для этого заметим, что *обыкновенный строковый литерал* также называют *узким строковым литералом* (narrow string literal).

[[lex.string]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/lex.string#7):

> **Ordinary string literals** and UTF-8 string literals **are also referred
> to as narrow string literals**.

Тогда `n` в нашем случае определяется следующим образом.

[[lex.string]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/lex.string#13):

> ...
>
> **The size of a narrow string literal is the total number of** escape
> sequences and **other characters**, plus at least one for the multibyte
> encoding of each universal-character-name, **plus one for the
> terminating '\0'**.

Таким образом, `n = 2 + 1 = 3` и тип `"42"` есть `const char [3]`.

---

Для выяснения типа `T` заметим, что выражение `"42"` является lvalue.

[[expr.prim.literal]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.prim.literal#1):

> ... **A string-literal is an lvalue**, a user-defined-literal has the same
> value category as the corresponding operator call expression described
> in, and any other literal is a prvalue.

Тогда для *продвигающей ссылки* ([forwarding reference](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/temp.deduct#def:forwarding_reference)) типа `T&&` дедукция `T` выполняется следующим образом (далее `P` — тип параметра, `A` — аргумента).

[[temp.deduct.call]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/temp.deduct.call#3):

> ... If P is a forwarding reference and the argument is an lvalue, the
> type “lvalue reference to A” is used in place of A for type deduction. ...

Таким образом, тип `T` дедуцируется как `const char (&) [3]`.

---

Чтобы выяснить тип `s` в параметре, заметим, что `T` является т.н. [typedef-name](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.typedef#nt:typedef-name) (в нашем случае [type-parameter](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/temp.param#nt:type-parameter) есть `typename T`, а [identifier](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/lex.name#nt:identifier) — `T`).

[[temp.param]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/temp.param#3):

> **A type-parameter whose identifier does not follow an ellipsis defines
> its identifier to be a typedef-name (if declared without template)** or
> template-name (if declared with template) in the scope of the template
> declaration. ...

Поэтому выполняется следующий пункт, известный как *сворачивание ссылок* ([reference collapsing](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.ref#note-3)) (в нашем случае `TR` есть `const char (&) [3]`, `T` в цитате (не путать с `T` из вопроса) — `const char [3]`).

[[dcl.ref]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.ref#6):

> **If a typedef-name** or a decltype-specifier **denotes a type TR that is a
> reference to a type T**, an attempt to create the type “lvalue reference
> to cv TR” creates the type “lvalue reference to T”, while **an attempt
> to create the type “rvalue reference to cv TR” creates the type TR**. ...

Таким образом, тип `s` в параметре равен `TR`, то есть `const char (&) [3]`.

---

Тип объекта `s` (точнее, сущности, названной с помощью выражения `s`) внутри функции `bar` остаётся таким же, как в параметре, однако само выражение (т.н. [id-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr#nt:id-expression)) `s` имеет тип `const char [3]`, что следует из пункта ниже.

[[expr.type]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.type#1):

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T”, the type is adjusted to T prior to any further
> analysis. ...

---

Чтобы узнать тип возвращаемого `std::forward<T>(s)` выражения, рассмотрим [объявления этой функции](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/forward#1).

```
template<class T> constexpr T&& forward(remove_reference_t<T>& t) noexcept;
template<class T> constexpr T&& forward(remove_reference_t<T>&& t) noexcept;
```

Согласно следующему пункту, в нашем случае используется первая версия.

[[forward]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/forward#2):

> *Mandates*: For the second overload, `is_­lvalue_­reference_­v<T>` is
> `false`.

Таким образом, для нашего типа `T`, равного `const char (&) [3]`, после преобразований получаем параметр `t`, имеющий тот же тип `const char (&) [3]`.

Параметр `t` инициализируется с помощью выражения `s`.

[[expr.call]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.call#7):

> When a function is called, each parameter is initialized with its
> corresponding argument. ...

После чего функция возвращает следующее выражение.

[[forward]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/forward#3):

> *Returns*: `static_­cast<T&&>(t)`.

Которое, в соответствии с ранее указанным правилом *сворачивания ссылок*, снова даёт тип `const char (&) [3]`.

Само же выражение `std::forward<T>(s)` в вызове `foo(std::forward<T>(s));` имеет тип `const char [3]` по тем же соображениям, что и выражение `s` внутри функции `bar`.

---

Осталось понять, почему `foo(const char [3])` вызывает именно версию `void foo(std::string&&)`. Для решения, какая функция будет вызвана, используется процесс *разрешения перегрузок* ([overload resolution](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.match#general-1)).

Обе перегрузки функции входят в множество *функций-кандидатов* ([candidate functions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.match#def:candidate)) согласно следующему пункту.

[[over.call.func]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.call.func#3):

> ... The name is looked up in the context of the function call
> following the normal rules for name lookup in expressions. The
> function declarations found by that lookup constitute the set of
> candidate functions. ...

Обе *функции-кандидата* также входят в множество *выполнимых функций* ([viable functions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.match.viable)), т.к. выполняются следующие 3 пункта.

- Количество аргументов совпадает с количеством параметров.

[[over.match.viable]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.match.viable#2):

> First, to be a viable function, a candidate function shall have enough
> parameters to agree in number with the arguments in the list. ...

- Функции не являются шаблонными.

[[over.match.viable]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.match.viable#3):

> Second, for a function to be viable, if it has associated constraints,
> those constraints shall be satisfied.

- Существуют *последовательности неявных преобразований* ([implicit conversion sequence](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.best.ics#def:conversion_sequence,implicit)) аргументов к параметрам (будут показаны далее).

[[over.match.viable]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.match.viable#4):

> Third, for F to be a viable function, there shall exist for each
> argument an implicit conversion sequence that converts that argument
> to the corresponding parameter of F. ...

На этом этапе, кстати, *функция-кандидат* `void foo(std::string&)` не вошла бы в множество *выполнимых*, но у нас такой перегрузки нет.

[[over.match.viable]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.match.viable#4):

> ... **If the parameter has reference type**, the implicit conversion
> sequence includes the operation of binding the reference, and **the
> fact that an lvalue reference to non-const cannot be bound to an
> rvalue** and that an rvalue reference cannot be bound to an lvalue
> **can affect the viability of the function**.

[[over.ics.ref]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.ics.ref#3):

> Except for an implicit object parameter, for which see
> [[over.match.funcs](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.match.funcs)], **an
> implicit conversion sequence cannot be formed if it requires binding
> an lvalue reference other than a reference to a non-volatile const
> type to an rvalue** or binding an rvalue reference to an lvalue other
> than a function lvalue. ...

В обоих случаях *последовательности неявных преобразований* являются *пользовательскими последовательностями преобразований* ([user-defined conversion sequence](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.ics.user#def:conversion_sequence,user-defined)). Такие преобразования, в свою очередь, состоят из 3 преобразований.

[[over.ics.user]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.ics.user#1):

> A user-defined conversion sequence consists of an initial standard
> conversion sequence followed by a user-defined conversion followed by
> a second standard conversion sequence. ...

Для обеих перегрузок первая *стандартная последовательность преобразований* ([standard conversion sequence](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/conv#def:conversion_sequence,standard)) есть преобразование `const char [3]` к `const char*` в [конструкторе строки](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/string.cons) `constexpr basic_string(const charT* s, const Allocator& a = Allocator())`.

[[over.ics.user]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.ics.user#1):

> ... If the user-defined conversion is specified by a constructor, the
> initial standard conversion sequence converts the source type to the
> type required by the argument of the constructor. ...

Второе, *пользовательское преобразование* ([user-defined conversion](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.conv#def:conversion,user-defined)), задаётся вызовом указанного выше *преобразующего конструктора* ([converting constructor](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.conv.ctor#def:constructor,converting)). Оно также одинаково для обеих *выполнимых функций*.

[[class.conv]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.conv#general-1):

> **Type conversions of class objects can be specified by constructors** and by conversion functions. ...

А вот последняя *стандартная последовательность преобразований* отличается у первой и второй перегрузок в том смысле, что *стандартная последовательность преобразований* из prvalue типа `std::string`, возвращённого после вызова *преобразующего конструктора* ранее, в rvalue ссылку `std::string&&` второй перегрузки считается лучшей *стандартной последовательностью преобразований*, чем преобразование того же prvalue `std::string` в lvalue ссылку `const std::string&` относительно отношения порядка [better conversion sequence](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.ics.rank#def:conversion_sequence,better).

[[over.ics.user]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.ics.user#2):

> The second standard conversion sequence converts the result of the
> user-defined conversion to the target type for the sequence; **any
> reference binding is included in the second standard conversion
> sequence**. ...

[[over.ics.rank]/3.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.ics.rank#3.2):

> Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than
> standard conversion sequence S2 if
>
> - ...
> - S1 and S2 include reference bindings and neither refers to an implicit object parameter of a non-static member function declared
>   without a ref-qualifier, and S1 binds an rvalue reference to an rvalue
>   and S2 binds an lvalue reference. ...
> - ...

Раз вторая *стандартная последовательность преобразований* в *пользовательской последовательности преобразований* для *выполнимой функции* `void foo(std::string&&)` лучше, то и сама *пользовательская последовательность преобразований* для этой версии лучше.

[[over.ics.rank]/3.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.ics.rank#3.3):

> **User-defined conversion sequence U1 is a better conversion sequence than another user-defined conversion sequence U2 if they contain the
> same** user-defined conversion function or **constructor** or they
> initialize the same class in an aggregate initialization **and** in
> either case **the second standard conversion sequence of U1 is better
> than the second standard conversion sequence of U2**. ...

Зная это, получаем, что *выполнимая функция* `void foo(std::string&&)` является единственно лучшей относительно отношения порядка [better viable function](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.match.best#def:overloading,resolution,better_viable_function) (здесь `ICSj(F)` — *последовательность неявных преобразований* для аргумента функции `F` с порядковым номером `j`).

[[over.match.best]/2.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.match.best#general-2.1):

> Given these definitions, **a viable function F1 is defined to be a
> better function than another viable function F2 if** for all arguments
> i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and then
>
> - **for some argument j, ICSj(F1) is a better conversion sequence than ICSj(F2)**, or, if not that,
> - ...

Наконец, раз эта *выполнимая функция* является единственно лучшей, именно она и выбирается в процессе *разрешения перегрузок*.

[[over.match.best]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.match.best#general-3):

> **If there is exactly one viable function that is a better function than
> all other viable functions, then it is the one selected by overload
> resolution**; otherwise the call is ill-formed. ...

---

---

Проверим типы с помощью средств языка. Для этого сначала вспомним, как работает `decltype`.

[[dcl.type.decltype]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.type.decltype#1):

> For an expression E, the type denoted by `decltype(E)` is defined as
> follows:
>
> - ...
> - otherwise, if E is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access, `decltype(E)` is the type of the
>   entity named by E. ...
> - otherwise, if E is an xvalue, `decltype(E)` is T&&, where T is the type of E;
> - otherwise, if E is an lvalue, `decltype(E)` is T&, where T is the type of E;
> - otherwise, `decltype(E)` is the type of E.

[Пример](https://godbolt.org/z/bbh15G), показывающий типы с помощью `decltype`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

using literal_type = const char [3];
using reference_type = const char (&) [3];

template<typename T>
void bar(T&& s) {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, reference_type>);   // deduction
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T&&, reference_type>); // reference collapsing

    // unparenthesized id-expression => type of s = T&& = reference_type
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(s), reference_type>);

    // parenthesized lvalue expression => literal_type + & = reference_type
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype((s)), reference_type>);

    // lvalue expression => literal_type + & = reference_type
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(std::forward<T>(s)), reference_type>);
}

int main() {
    // lvalue expression => literal_type + & = reference_type
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype("42"), reference_type>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype("42")>, literal_type>);

    bar("42");
}
```

[Ещё один пример](https://godbolt.org/z/1qvf9a), демонстрирующий типы с помощью диагностик компиляторов:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

void foo(std::string& s) {
    std::cout << "non-const &\n";
}

template<typename T>
void bar(T&& s) {
    foo(std::forward<T>(s));
}

int main() {
    bar("42");
}
```

Упрощённый вывод:

> *x86-64 gcc 10.1*:
>
> > In instantiation of 'void bar(T&&) [with **T = `const char (&)[3]`**]':
> >
> > error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type `std::string&` to an
> > rvalue of type `std::string`
> >
> > `foo(std::forward<T>(s));`
> >
> > note: after user-defined conversion:
> >
> > `basic_string(const _CharT* __s, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc())`
>
> *x86-64 clang 10.0.0*:
>
> > error: no matching function for call to `foo`
> >
> > `foo(std::forward<T>(s));`
> >
> > in instantiation of function template specialization **`bar<char const (&) [3]>`** requested here
> >
> > `bar("42");`
> >
> > candidate function not viable: no known conversion from **`char const[3]`** to
> > `std::string &` for 1st argument
> >
> > `void foo(std::string& s) {`
>
> *x64 msvc v19.24*:
>
> > error C2664: `void foo(std::string &)`: cannot convert argument 1 from **`const char [3]`** to `std::string &`
> >
> > note: see reference to function template instantiation `void bar<const char(&) [3]>(T)` being compiled
> >
> > with **T=`const char (&)[3]`**

Comment: Ох, подробный ответ, где высказываемые утверждения активно подкрепляются ссылками на соответствующие пункты стандарта языка. Это хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуем так:

`bar("42") ->` вызывает `foo(std::forward<char[3]>(s)("42"))`

Теперь ищем функцию  `foo(const char*)`, ее нет, но зато есть версии, аргумент которых такой тип, что `const char*` неявно преобразуется в него. ОК _ вызываем ->`foo( std::forward<std::string>( std::string("42") ) )`.
Но, с другой стороны std::forward принимает `std::remove_reference_t<_Ty>` и так как
аргумент функции `std::forward`  очевидно есть временная переменная, то он будет передан как `std::remove_reference_t<std::string&&>`, а это в свою очередь есть псевдоним `std::string&&` и  поэтому
вызовется именно специализация `std::forward<std::string&&>`, которая и вернет  `std::string&&` и вызовется перегрузка именно с таким аргументом.

Answer (score 0):

Тут функция `bar` вообще значения не имеет:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void foo(const std::string&) {
    std::cout << "&\n";
}

void foo(std::string&& s) {
    std::cout << "&&\n";
}

int main() {
    foo("42");
}
```

Тоже печатает `&&`, потому что для временного объекта `"42"` лучше подходит перегрузка с `&&`. А вот для обычной переменной, наоборот, печатает `&`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void foo(const std::string&) {
    std::cout << "&\n";
}

void foo(std::string&& s) {
    std::cout << "&&\n";
}

int main() {
    using namespace std::literals::string_literals;
    auto x = "42"s;
    foo(x);
}
```