# c++ про rvalue, move и forward

Tags: c++, move, конструктор-копирования, перемещение, forward

Всем привет! Правильно ли я понимаю, что конструктор вида:

```
    template<typename T>
    struct myobj
    {
        T* pointer;
        myobj()
        {
         //something...
        }
        myobj(T&& arg)
        {
            T* var;
            new(var) T(std::forward(arg));
    //утечка? Запись непойми куда? Ну и ладно, код чисто для демонстрации вопроса)
        }
    };
```

Будет универсальным как для копирования, так и для перемещения?
Если я напишу(myobj2 просто какой-то класс):

```
myobj2 a;
myobj<myobj2> object(a);
myobj<myobj2> object2(std::move(a));
```

То в 1м случае скопируется, а во втором сработает перемещение? И если да, то сколько фактически компилятор создаст конструкторов? 2 одинаковые штуки(для lvalue и rvalue), отличающиеся лишь частью с forward или как?

P.S. и работает ли forward так же, когда используется вне шаблонов,как просто функция?

Comment: Нет, это обычная rvalue ссылка, т.к. конструктор нешаблонный. Про универсальные (forwarding) ссылки можете [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1150317/312941) и [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) почитать.

Comment: Убедитесь, что пример вообще собирается. Вы специально навесили `template` на весь класс, или промахнулись мимо конструктора? Еще забыт конструктор по умолчанию, раз вы делаете `myobj a;`. У `forward` забыт шаблонный аргумент.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну думаю не важно, куда  я навесил template, этот класс чисто для демонстрации. Конструктор по-умолчанию есть, он просто дефолтный от компилятора, да и для примера не важен.
P.S. задам страшный вопрос, а как выделять в комментарии куски кода? Просто обычные '' и прочие комбо из кавычек почему-то не работают.

Comment: С выделением памяти какая-то фигня...

Comment: @Qwertiy да оно не важно, пусть там утечка, код чисто для уточнения моего вопроса)

Comment: @SupremeMachine, там не утечка, а наоборот запись по мусорному указателю.

Comment: @Qwerity ну и это тоже, и утечка, и запись непойми куда, но повторюсь, это абстрактный пример)

Comment: @SupremeMachine, представить код в комментарии можно в "обратных" кавычках -- `char x;` (саму обратную кавычку внутри кода надо экранировать бэкслешем (`code \` quoted code \``) (однако, отформатировать код в нескльких строках система не дает)

Comment: *"ну думаю не важно, куда я навесил template"* — вот именно, что важно. В текущем виде тут нет forwarding ссылок. [Нетрудно проверить](https://godbolt.org/z/1a4vqMf88), что в первом случае будет ошибка компиляции. Два одинаковых конструктора с разными реализациями нельзя в принципе получить из-за ODR. Если действительно хотите разобраться, то всё ещё рекомендую прочитать ссылки из прошлого комментария — тогда и ответ на вопрос в P.S. должен стать понятен.

Answer (score 1):

В предоставленном коде ошибка.
Компилятор подставит тип T в конструктор от T&&, т.е 1 конструктор от rvalue.

```
template<>
struct myobj<std::basic_string<char> >
{
  inline myobj();
  
  inline myobj(std::basic_string<char> && arg)
  {
    std::basic_string<char> * var;
    new (reinterpret_cast<void *>(var))std::basic_string<char>(std::forward<std::basic_string<char> >(arg));
  }
  
};
```

И вызов

```
myobj<myobj2> object(a);
```

Попросту не соберется с такой ошибкой

```
no matching constructor for initialization of 'myobj<std::string>' (aka 'myobj<basic_string<char>>')
        myobj<std::string> object(a);
                           ^      ~
/home/insights/insights.cpp:11:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: expects an rvalue for 1st argument
    myobj(T&& arg)
    ^
/home/insights/insights.cpp:6:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
    myobj()
```

Чтобы все работало так, как Вы хотите, нужно чтобы и сам конструктор был шаблонным:

```
template <class U>
myobj(U&& arg)
{
    T* var;
    new(var) T(std::forward<U>(arg));
    //утечка? Запись непойми куда? Ну и ладно, код чисто для демонстрации вопроса)
}
```

Тогда компилятор сгенерирует

```
struct myobj<std::basic_string<char> >
{
  inline myobj();
  
  template<class U>
  inline myobj(U&& arg);
  
  template<>
  inline myobj<std::basic_string<char> &>(std::basic_string<char> & arg)
  {
    std::basic_string<char> * var;
    new (reinterpret_cast<void *>(var))std::basic_string<char>(std::forward<std::basic_string<char> &>(arg));
  }
  
  template<>
  inline myobj<std::basic_string<char> >(std::basic_string<char> && arg)
  {
    std::basic_string<char> * var;
    new (reinterpret_cast<void *>(var))std::basic_string<char>(std::forward<std::basic_string<char> >(arg));
  }
};
```

Comment: а зачем у forward прописывать тип шаблонный? Разве компилятор не догадается какой нужно подставить?

Comment: Привычка. Если использовать Variadic template, то без явного указания типа пака будет ошибка компиляции